# how to fork a package of flutter and change it

Tags: git, flutter

There is a file which draws the dayPicker widget in flutter. it is located here:

> {flutter_dir}/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart

how can I fork it and edit it to use it as a package?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file from the location and do the edit, save it. Then it would work in your local system. And it won't impact any other programmer, since I guess the package folder is already put in `.gitignore`